# How to add open vscode with GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Vscode has an issue with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> where it returns an undefined key and this topic has been covered before in this link https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48480. I solved this issue by running this command `GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" code` in the terminal but is there a way of saving this command in a path? I tried exporting it in my `.bashrc` but Vscode still runs into that issue.

Edit: I solved the solution by adding an alias `alias code="GTK_IM_MODULE=xim code"` but if I open vscode application rather than the terminal then I run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"` in my `/etc/profile`. That way I open vscode anywhere and not just depend on an alias in the terminal.

Then you have to run it to take effect using `source /etc/profile` or `. /etc/profile`. But in my case even after running the profile and reopening Vscode, it didn't recognize <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>. I had to restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late, but here's what I've done:

Install the **menulibre** package: `sudo apt-get install menulibre`

Look for the programming section, and add the env variable to the vscode launch option, like so:

[image]

Do the same to the URL handler entry!

Close any vscode instances and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Just type the following command and it will do the rest for you:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cra0zy/code-nautilus/master/install.sh | bash
```